# Failed to upload of CSV excel file

Tags: windows-7

I tried to upload a CSV excel file in another work but failed as itgives the command "improper data file.Actual column and CSV columnsare not same or data ina file are not comma(,) separated.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your csv file in a text editor (Notepad++ is good for this) to make sure :

1. no embedded commas. If there are, use search and replace to change the delimiter-commas to '|' (pipe character)
2. Every row has the same quantity of delimiters (same as saying 'make sure all rows of data have the same number of columns).

Also, try harder to ask well-formed questions. I sometimes have a friend look at my questions before I post them.